# What happens when devices are created and how do I emulate the behaviour myself?

Tags: system, devices, emulation

The reason I ask the question is because I would like to emulate a device or create a device (specifically a usb-device) on disk without connecting the physical device.

What I would like is to create a device such that it shows up in the **lsusb** output.

What I have tried so far is creating a file with **dd** and using **losetup** to connect the created file with a loop device (/dev/loop*). That however doesn't create a message in **dmesg**.

Edit:

As requested here's more info on my dilemma.
I bought a USB-stick quite a while back with a language trainer that has limited it's execution (.exe)to the USB-stick. Since wine doesn't transfer the USB device data to the exe I was forced to use it in a VM. Since I use the stick on a VM, I thought I could emulate it on my host and go completely virtual - no need for the physical usb-stick.

Comment: Have a look at the `udevadm` manpage, it may be of some help.

Comment: @aquaherd That indeed was somewhat helpful. If I understood the manual right I think I can create kernel events. I'll get some more information on the `sysfs` so that I know what attributes to set when creating an event. If hope one of those attributes is a reference to a file that will represent the device's storage.

Comment: Yes. you can't fake a non-existing device but you can persuade the system to re-detect plugged devices or fake/trigger their arrival and departure events.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for would be called a virtual USB device. I don't think the standard kernel contains anything like that.

Some virtual machines can emulate USB devices for the guest (as opposed to relaying data to a hardware USB device connected to the host). For example, [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB) can emulate USB storage and human interface devices.

The [gadget](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) framework is a way for Linux devices to function as USB peripherals (USB is highly asymmetrical: devices and hosts do different things). There is also a [usbnet](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/) driver to relay USB connections over Ethernet; you could use this and write a program that talks the Ethernet protocol.

Using these indirect methods will not necessarily be easier than implementing your own USB driver. If you choose to go that route, [*Linux Device Drivers (3rd ed.)*](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is the book to read.

What you're asking is not likely to be easy. If you explain what your underlying problem is, someone may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. It delves deeper than I thought I'd have to go and I hope I won't have to do any coding.   I'll edit my question's description to be more specific about my goals.

Comment: @UncleJack Assuming the USB stick is an ordinary one and not a dual device with a built-in cryptographic module (these exist but tend to be used to protect $10,000-per-user software, not language trainers), what you need is specifically to emulate a USB **storage** device. KVM can do this out of the box (see my link). I don't think VirtualBox can do it, and I don't know about VMWare.

Comment: I'll fiddle around and see if I can get expected results. Ty